# Add a verified role for a new user based on a reaction to an embed

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I am trying to create a verification system for users joining my server. They must react to the correct emoji to be given the member role. I have spent around 14+ hours reading the documentation and even tried using a collection and a try-catch block. How can I get the event handler to recognize the member and message properties so this event can function accordingly?

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.channels.get('549387603773828971').send(embed).then(async embedMessage => {
    await embedMessage.react('✔️');
    await embedMessage.react('❌');
  });

  client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "✔️") {
      //assign role to new user   
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌")
    // tell user to react to the correct emote
  });
});
```

Comment: My **best** guess is that the message is *cached* Are you reacting to the message in the same code-run as the message?
But otherwise nothing looks to be wrong. What error are you getting? or whats NOT happening.

Answer (score 0):

First I fetched the `guildMember` using `reaction.message` to get all message properties and methods. After this, I fetched the role by its name using the `reaction.message.guild` properties and methods.

For your message, I also used the `reaction.message.channel` methods.

Try using the following code:

```js
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  member.guild.channels.get('549387603773828971').send(embed).then(async embedMessage => {
    await embedMessage.react('✔️');
    await embedMessage.react('❌');
  });

  client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (reaction.emoji.name === "✔️") {
        const guildMember = reaction.message.guild.members.get(user.id);
        if (!guildMember) throw 'Couldn\'t get guildMember!'

        const roleToAssign = reaction.message.guild.roles.find(r => r.name === 'NAME OF THE ROLE')
        if (!roleToAssign) throw 'Couldn\'t get roleToAssign!'

        await guildMember.addRole(roleToAssign)
    } else if (reaction.emoji.name === "❌")
        reaction.message.channel.send('Tell user to react to the correct emote');
  });
});
```